Equation connecting The Riemann Zeta function and the Gamma function
I am studying indipendently analitic number theory (I started with Apostol's book) and have now developed an interest in the Riemann Zeta function.
It is often possible while studying the Riemann zeta function to come across the following equation:
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{(1-2^{1-s})\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}$$
for Re(s)>0.
This is one of the many equations connecting the Riemann zeta function and the Gamma function.
It is supposed to be explained in "Higher Transcendental Functions" by Erdélyi, but the proof there is missing all the details so I find it incomprehensible,  I find it surprising that it is hard to find a rigorous proofm, can anyone help me?

A suggestion: add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

If you write
$$\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,x^{s-1}\,e^{-(n+1) x}$$
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty (-1)^n\,x^{s-1}\,e^{-(n+1) x}\,dx=(-1)^n\, (n+1)^{-s} \,\Gamma (s)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_n=2^{-s} \left(2^s-2\right) \zeta (s)
   \Gamma (s)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta (s)
   \Gamma (s)$$ Then, the formula.

Hi thanks for your reply, I'm assuming that you are using the formula for the alternating geometric series in the first line, the formula should be:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
while you seem to be using something like:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
am I missing something?

@Zackury Claude is expanding $x/(1+x)$ with $e^{-x}$ in place of $x$.
